# Фильтрация по текущему году, кварталу, месяцу в отчете Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Необходимо фильтровать исходный набор данных, на основе которого отображаются визуализации, по дате:
1. с начала текущего года
2. с начала текущего квартала
3. с начала текущего месяца.

В отчет должны попадать строки, даты которых после начала выбранного периода.

Сложность в том, что необходима возможность для пользователя переключать период в отчете **без выбора конкретного года/квартала/месяца**.
Т.е. пользователь должен кликнуть на название периода (в слайсере?), по текущей дате автоматически должна определиться начальная дата периода и данные пересчитаны по отфильтрованному набору.

По отдельности задачи все понятны, но как это реализовать всё вместе в рамках функциональности Power BI - не понятно. Есть идеи?

Answer (score 0):

В слайсере этого не получится сделать. Для этого нужен выползающий список.
Предлагаю в редакторе запросов добавить три столбца на основании даты.
Затем в BI нужно выбрать элемент SmartFilter by OKViz, выбрать их нужно три и поочередно в каждый добавить дату(квартал, год, месяц)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]